# Wix run second action after first is finish

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, wix3.6

Then I install my setup and check checkbox for launch my application then pressing finish the Setup run both programs at once(setup.exe and open picture). Is the way to run setup.exe and then setup.exe is finish instalation run picture. I mean is the way to run actions one by one and not all at the same time?? Here is my .wxs code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Language="1033" Name="xxxxxx" Manufacturer="xxxx LTD">
    <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes"/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myapplication.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="2" /> 
    <Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1" />

    <!-- Step 1: Define the directory structure -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="InstallFiles" Name="My Application Name">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

  <!-- set property and launch the first exe -->
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="PrepareLaunchApplication1">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication1">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>

  <!-- set property and launch the second exe -->
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="PrepareLaunchApplication2">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication2">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
</UI>
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch My Application Name" />

<CustomAction Id="PrepareLaunchApplication1" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#Setup.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication1"
    BinaryKey="WixCA"
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" 
    Return="check"
    Execute="immediate"/>

<CustomAction Id="PrepareLaunchApplication2" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#a.png]" />  
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication2" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA" 
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes"
    Return="check"/>

    <!-- Step 2: Add files to your installer package -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="InstallFiles">
      <Component Id="Setup.exe">
        <File Id="Setup.exe" KeyPath="yes"
              Name="Setup.exe" Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>
 <Component Id="a.png">
        <File Id="a.png" KeyPath="yes"
              Name="a.png" Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>  
    </DirectoryRef>

    <!-- Step 3: Tell WiX to install the files -->
    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">

      <ComponentRef Id="Setup.exe" />
      <ComponentRef Id="a.png" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for your case, use InstallExecuteSequence. WiX is a declarative language, so you have to define the sequence otherwise everything will be executed as is. I have not tested this, but the naming for the CustomAction that you want to execute has to match the CustomAction invoking WixCA. I do not know how the values in the CustomAction is going to be invoked, but this snippet of code should give you an idea on how to place CustomActions in a sequence.

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication1" Property="WixShellExecTarget"Value="[#Setup.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication1"
    BinaryKey="WixCA"
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" 
    Return="check"
    Execute="immediate"/>

<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication2" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#a.png]" />  
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication2" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA" 
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes"
    Return="check"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="LaunchApplication1" After="InstallFiles"/>
    <Custom Action="LaunchApplication2" After="LaunchApplication1"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris N. for your answer, i do that you say , but i receive an error , where can be a problem? we error message is : (Compile target) ->
  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SetupIup\Product.wxs(48): error CNDL0181: The Custom/@After attribute's value 'LaunchApplication2' is invalid because it would make this action dependent upon itself.  Please change the value to the name of a different action. [C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SetupIup\SetupIup.wixproj]

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo as you can't schedule a task waiting on itself. I changed <Custom Action="LaunchApplication2" After="LaunchApplication2"/> to <Custom Action="LaunchApplication2" After="LaunchApplication1" />.The "After" property is to specify when the action will be execute which in this case "LaunchApplication2" will execute after "LaunchApplication1" is complete.

Comment: N , now i have 4 same errors: one of error is :   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SetupIup - test sequi\Product.wxs(40): error LGHT0092: Location of symbol related to previous error. [C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SetupIup - test sequi\SetupIup.wixproj]

Comment: maybe you know where is a problem? error LGHT0092 ant LGHT0091 , sorry for that , but i try anything :(